# Implement comparison operator for Enum type in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I'm really beginner in Python, so please forgive me if this is something obvious.

I have an enum class, and I want to be able to compare the members. Below code seems to do what I want ( but not how I want )

```
import enum

class AB(enum.Enum):

    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    d=4
    e=5

    @classmethod
    def le(cls, a, b):
        lst = [cls.a, cls.b, cls.c, cls.d, cls.e]
        ia = lst.index(a)
        ib = lst.index(b)
        return(ia <= ib)


if AB.le(AB.a, AB.b):
    print('Do this')
else:
    print('Do that')
```

Now my question is how to code the comparison operator `__le__` so that I can run the below code instead?

```
mem1 = AB.a
mem2 = AB.c

if mem1 <= mem2 :
    print('Do this')
else:
    print('Do that')
```

Comment: It's much like implementing `__le__` for any other class really. `def __le__(self, other): return self.value <= other.value`

Comment: Thanks! that simple! I was unnecessarily trying to avoid 'self' and use a class method. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Enum` subclasses are somewhat special in that all enumeration values become *instances* of the class (with a few tweaks). This does mean you can 'just' define a normal method on the `Enum` subclass and they'll be available on each enumeration value.

This applies to special methods like `object.__le__()` too; just define it as a regular method, *not* a `classmethod`:

```
class AB(enum.Enum):
    def __le__(self, b):
        return self.value <= b.value

    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = 5
```

Note that I used the [instance attribute `.value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes), just like you can do `AB.a.value`.

You could also use the [`IntEnum` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum); that makes each enumeration value a subclass of `int`, and they can be compared *naturally*:

```
class AB(enum.IntEnum):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = 5
```

Demo:

```
>>> import enum
>>> class AB(enum.Enum):
...     def __le__(self, b):
...         return self.value <= b.value
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
...     c = 3
...     d = 4
...     e = 5
...
>>> AB.a <= AB.b
True
>>> AB.b <= AB.a
False
>>> AB.a < AB.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: AB() < AB()
```

and using `IntEnum` as the base:

```
>>> class AB(enum.IntEnum):
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
...     c = 3
...     d = 4
...     e = 5
...
>>> AB.a <= AB.b
True
>>> AB.b >= AB.a
True
>>> AB.b > AB.a
True
>>> AB.a + AB.b
3
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the information I needed. Marking as answer!

Comment: IntEnum bring in these by default? Mostly i need just int values. I should not add those like that last example though!

Comment: @kollery: each value object in the enum is *also* an integer, so you can use them in any way integers can be used, without having to use the `.value` attribute. You can use them to index lists, for example: `l = ['foo', 'bar']`, then `l[AB.b]`. Etc. And yes, that means they work in arithmetic too.

Comment: **Avoid `IntEnum` like the plague it is.** The `IntEnum` subclass violates [various contractual agreements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269589/2809027) otherwise guaranteed by the `Enum` superclass. In particular, `IntEnum` instances will be comparable against arbitrary integers (_which is bad_) and arbitrary other `IntEnum` instances (_which is even worse_).

Comment: Likewise, the `__lt__()` method as defined above fails to adhere to the rich comparator API. The `NotImplemented` constant should be returned if the passed object has a different type and is thus incomparable with the current `Enum` instance.

Comment: Lastly, the `@functools.total_ordering` class decorator may be used to automatically define the four remaining comparison methods (i.e., `__ge__()`, `__gt__()`, `__le__()`, and `__ne__()`). Since the `Enum` superclass already supplies an `__eq__()` implementation, the resulting enums will then be comparable with _all_ possible operators – not merely `<`.

Comment: For a working implementation addressing these issues, see [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s explanatory [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269589/2809027) at this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268052).

Comment: @CecilCurry: the `__lt__` method is merely a simplified version of the attempt the OP made, adding in `NotImplemented` is of course trivial. Using `IntEnum` is a tradeoff; using it *may* be bad software design, it is not a *plague*, it won't horribly break all your code. Please don't resort to hyperbole like that.

Comment: @CecilCurry, i see what you are implying. In a bigger code base, using enum as int can have headaches later. Looking at the suggested solution, i modified my IntEnum to use total_ordering. I was expecting a simple switch,  but then, i realized that elsewhere i have used it as an index to a list. such things can cause confusion and bug later. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

The  `__le__` method should be called as a member function of the LHS operand and takes the RHS operand as its parameter.

However it's not clear from your code which member variables of an `AB` object should be used in the comparison, so I can't really write the code for you.

Roughly it should look something like:

```
def __le__(self, b):
    return # do something with self and b to figure out which one would be <=
```

Comment: Yes. I had somehow got tracked myself into thinking 'classmethod' is the way for enums. not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rawing and @machine yearning,

```
import enum

class AB(enum.Enum):

    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    d=4
    e=5

    def __le__(self, other):
        return(self.value <= other.value)


if AB.c <= AB.d:
    print('Do this')
else:
    print('Do that')
```