# How to compare Enums in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, compare

Since Python 3.4, the `Enum` class exists.

I am writing a program, where some constants have a specific order and I wonder which way is the most pythonic to compare them:

```
class Information(Enum):
    ValueOnly = 0
    FirstDerivative = 1
    SecondDerivative = 2
```

Now there is a method, which needs to compare a given `information` of `Information` with the different enums:

```
information = Information.FirstDerivative
print(value)
if information >= Information.FirstDerivative:
    print(jacobian)
if information >= Information.SecondDerivative:
    print(hessian)
```

The direct comparison does not work with Enums, so there are three approaches and I wonder which one is preferred:

Approach 1: Use values:

```
if information.value >= Information.FirstDerivative.value:
     ...
```

Approach 2: Use IntEnum:

```
class Information(IntEnum):
    ...
```

Approach 3: Not using Enums at all:

```
class Information:
    ValueOnly = 0
    FirstDerivative = 1
    SecondDerivative = 2
```

Each approach works, Approach 1 is a bit more verbose, while Approach 2 uses the not recommended IntEnum-class, while  and Approach 3 seems to be the way one did this before Enum was added.

I tend to use Approach 1, but I am not sure.

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Could you quote that "*not recommended* IntEnum-class", please ? Docs for 3.7.1 are not deprecating it at all.

Comment: Sure, from the Docs: “For the majority of new code, Enum and Flag are strongly recommended, since IntEnum and IntFlag break some semantic promises of an enumeration (by being comparable to integers, and thus by transitivity to other unrelated enumerations). IntEnum and IntFlag should be used only in cases where Enum and Flag will not do; for example, when integer constants are replaced with enumerations, or for interoperability with other systems.”

Comment: Approach 1 works for me thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I hadn't encountered Enum before so I scanned the doc (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) ... and found OrderedEnum (section 8.13.13.2)  Isn't this what you want? From the doc:

```
>>> class Grade(OrderedEnum):
...     A = 5
...     B = 4
...     C = 3
...     D = 2
...     F = 1
...
>>> Grade.C < Grade.A
True
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work due to unfixed Python bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue30545
You should always override comparator methods like __eq__ and __lt__

Comment: @asu there is no unfixed bug, the issues in that thread are not a problem with `Enum` itself, and in any case, this example **does** override the comparison operators.

Comment: Can't seem to import in Python 3.6, `ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedEnum'`?

**EDIT:** It looks like this is an "Interesting Example" and not actually in the standard python library. You'd need to copy the snippet from the docs to use it.

Comment: The documentation for OrderedEnum has been moved to here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#orderedenum

Answer (score 77):

You should always implement the rich comparison operaters if you want to use them with an `Enum`. Using the `functools.total_ordering` class decorator, you only need to implement an `__eq__` method along with a single ordering, e.g. `__lt__`. Since `enum.Enum` already implements `__eq__` this becomes even easier:

```
>>> import enum
>>> from functools import total_ordering
>>> @total_ordering
... class Grade(enum.Enum):
...   A = 5
...   B = 4
...   C = 3
...   D = 2
...   F = 1
...   def __lt__(self, other):
...     if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
...       return self.value < other.value
...     return NotImplemented
... 
>>> Grade.A >= Grade.B
True
>>> Grade.A >= 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: Grade() >= int()
```

Terrible, horrible, ghastly things can happen with `IntEnum`. It was mostly included for backwards-compatibility sake, enums used to be implemented by subclassing `int`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum):

> For the vast majority of code, Enum is strongly recommended, since
>   IntEnum breaks some semantic promises of an enumeration (by being
>   comparable to integers, and thus by transitivity to other unrelated
>   enumerations). It should be used only in special cases where there’s
>   no other choice; for example, when integer constants are replaced with
>   enumerations and backwards compatibility is required with code that
>   still expects integers.

Here's an example of why you don't want to do this:

```
>>> class GradeNum(enum.IntEnum):
...   A = 5
...   B = 4
...   C = 3
...   D = 2
...   F = 1
... 
>>> class Suit(enum.IntEnum):
...   spade = 4
...   heart = 3
...   diamond = 2
...   club = 1
... 
>>> GradeNum.A >= GradeNum.B
True
>>> GradeNum.A >= 3
True
>>> GradeNum.B == Suit.spade
True
>>>
```

Comment: Great description, thanks a lot. Just one question: You `return NotImplemented` instead of `raise NotImplemented`. Is there a general rule, when to use return and when raise?

Comment: @SebastianWerk Well, you cannot `raise NotImplemented` because it is not an exception. It is a built-in singleton. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/constants.html#NotImplemented), it is there for the special case of the rich-comparison operators. The `NotImplementedError`, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError), is there for when "abstract methods should raise this exception when they require derived classes to override the method.
".

Comment: @SebastianWerk Also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplemented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror

Comment: **Excellent answer,** good Sir. This approach is a succinct – albeit less efficient – alternative to the `OrderedEnum` class detailed in the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#orderedenum). While the `OrderedEnum` solution of manually implementing all comparison operators _is_ modestly faster, the `@total_ordering` solution given above has its merits. Brevity is a thankless virtue. Relatedly, does anyone know why `OrderedEnum` was merely documented rather than added to the `enum` module?

Comment: Is there a python `Enum` construct or similar that actually kinda .. _works_ ?  Adding @total_ordering and implementing comparison operators is _not_ something should have to code ourselves. This is too much boilerplate.

Comment: It seems you are implementing the `__lt__` (i.e. less than) method but in your example you are performing a greater than (or equal to) comparison. How does that work? Is it because you are comparing Grade against Grade and therefore the direction of comparison is relative? Does that mean that if you are only going to perform symmetric comparisons it's enough to only implement one of the `__gt__` / `__lt__` - methods of your own choosing?

Comment: @Nermin no, it's because I used the [`@functools.total_ordering` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

Comment: I implemented only the `__gt__` method instead of `__lt__` and it worked the same.

Comment: @Nermin yes, again, that works because I used the [`@functools.total_ordering` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering). Did you read the linked documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple decorator to resolve this too:

```py
from enum import Enum
from functools import total_ordering

def enum_ordering(cls):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if type(other) == type(self):
            return self.value < other.value

        raise ValueError("Cannot compare different Enums")

    setattr(cls, '__lt__', __lt__)
    return total_ordering(cls)


@enum_ordering
class Foos(Enum):
    a = 1
    b = 3
    c = 2

assert Names.a < Names.c
assert Names.c < Names.b
assert Names.a != Foos.a
assert Names.a < Foos.c # Will raise a ValueError
```

For bonus points you could implement the other methods in @VoteCoffee's answer above

Answer (score 1):

Combining some of the above ideas, you can subclass enum.Enum to make it comparable to string/numbers and then build your enums on this class instead:

```
import numbers
import enum


class EnumComparable(enum.Enum):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.value > other.value
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
                return self.value > other
        except:
            pass
        return NotImplemented

    def __lt__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.value < other.value
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
                return self.value < other
        except:
            pass
        return NotImplemented

    def __ge__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.value >= other.value
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
                return self.value >= other
            if isinstance(other, str):
                return self.name == other
        except:
            pass
        return NotImplemented

    def __le__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.value <= other.value
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
                return self.value <= other
            if isinstance(other, str):
                return self.name == other
        except:
            pass
        return NotImplemented

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self == other
        try:
            return self.value == other.value
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
                return self.value == other
            if isinstance(other, str):
                return self.name == other
        except:
            pass
        return NotImplemented
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who want to use the `==` with two enum instances like that: `enum_instance_1 == enum_instance_2`

just add the `__eq__` method in your Enum class as follows:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.__class__ is other.__class__ and other.value == self.value
```

Comment: This is totally unnecessary... this `==` behavior **already exists** for instances of classes that inherit from `enum.Enum` or use `enum.EnumMeta` as their metaclass. Note, you can also just use `is` to compare enums!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python 3.9. https://pypi.org/project/ordered-enum/

```
pip install ordered_enum
```

Then

```py
from ordered_enum import OrderedEnum

class Information(OrderedEnum):
    ValueOnly = 0
    FirstDerivative = 1
    SecondDerivative = 2

print(Information.ValueOnly < Information.FirstDerivative)
```