Check if value is in enum fails
I am super confused how neither of these work. Can someone help me understand what's going on and why it prints "BAD" and "Value does not exist"?
from enum import Enum

class EventType(Enum):
    USER_LOGIN = 1,
    USER_LOGOUT = 2,

    @classmethod
    def has_value(cls, value):
        return value in cls._value2member_map_

eventType = 2
if not EventType.has_value(eventType):
    print("BAD")
else:
    print("GOOD")
    
if eventType in EventType.__members__.values():
    print("Value exists")
else:
    print("Value does not exist")


As for __members__.values(), it contains the enumeration values not the integers themselves.

I'm running Python 3.9 in the AWS Lambda environment. Also, I tried the code above in several online IDEs and it keeps failing.

What do you get if you print out cls._value2member_map_?  On that note, you shouldn't depend upon private methods.

(I also get BAD / Value does not exist in 3.13.0). Note that you've defined your values as tuples, not scalars as you might have expected. My linter actually automatically replaced your code with USER_LOGIN = (1,) and USER_LOGOUT = (2,) when I pasted it into my IDE. Remove the , after your values and you will get GOOD / Value does not exist. Go from there.

OMFG yes the comma! My front-end is in TS and I copy those enums over a lot. Thank you!!!

note, you don't need this method, you can just use x in EventType

As @msanford said in the comments, remove the trailing commas from your values -- they are creating tuples.

To help you debug it, try looking at what the cls._value2member_map_ really looks like.
    @classmethod
    def has_value(cls, value):
        print(cls._value2member_map_)
        return value in cls._value2member_map_

On my python3.12 installation, I get this output:
{(1,): <EventType.USER_LOGIN: (1,)>, (2,): <EventType.USER_LOGOUT: (2,)>}

which sort of helps explains it -- the Enum constants are stored internally as tuples (I didn't catch why -- looks like the comment section caught it)

If you can, I'd recommend changing the baseeclass to IntEnum and taking advantage of this in syntax to use a documented technique to test membership like this:
from enum import IntEnum

class EventType(IntEnum):
    USER_LOGIN = 1
    USER_LOGOUT = 2

print(2 in EventType)
print(3 in EventType)


EDIT: if you fix the constant definitions to not be tuples, then you can use enum.Enum as a baseclass and avoid the IntEnum pitfalls the others are describing in the comments.
from enum import Enum

class EventType(Enum):
    USER_LOGIN = 1
    USER_LOGOUT = 2

print(2 in EventType)
print(3 in EventType)


They are stored as tuples because 1, is a tuple.

"Enum constants are stored internally as tuples" because they are tuples. And no, don't use IntEnum

@juanpa.arrivillaga, why not IntEnum?

@DanielWalker because it defeats the entire purpose of enums: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269589/5014455

@DanielWalker: Because an Enum with the same value as a different Enum will not compare equal, but an IntEnum with the same value as a different IntEnum will.
